# My Java methods are not running correctly and causing my program to compile incorrectly

Tags: java

I am writing a program that will prompt the user to enter a temp as a an integer, then prompt the user to select what scale that temp is in, either fahrenheit, celsius, or kelvin. Then it prompts the user to select what temp they would like to convert to, from the 3 scale choices, then calculates the conversion and displays the final temp. My program currently runs but incorrectly and I have been staring at this for a couple of days now and I am not sure why it is compiling the way it is. I am still fairly new to coding this is a class assignment that I have been working on just looking for some advice.

package tempconverter;
import java.util.*;

public class TempConverter 
{

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    double temp1;
    double convertTo;
    double finalTemp;
    double currScale;
    char cont='E';
    char process='P';
    int scale1=0;
    int scale2=0;

    do
    {
        //input
        getTemp();
        scaleOne(scale1);
        toScale(scale2);

        //process


        System.out.print("Your final temp is: " +convert()+toScale(scale2));

    }while(cont=='N');
}   
    private static double getTemp()
    {
         double temp;
         double currentTemp;
         Scanner userIn= new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.print("Enter a temperature to convert ");
         while(!userIn.hasNextDouble())
         {
          System.out.println("That is not a valid temperature!");
          System.out.print("Re-enter a temperature: ");
          userIn.next();
         }
         temp=userIn.nextDouble();



         return temp;
    }

    private static String scaleOne(int userChoice)
    {

        Scanner userIn= new Scanner(System.in);



        System.out.print("What scale is your temp currently in?"+
                          "1: Fahrenheit" + 
                          "2: Celsius" + 
                          "3: Kelvin" + 
                          "Please enter 1, 2, or 3: ");


        String scale="";

        switch(userChoice)
        {
            case 1:
            {scale= "Fahrenheit";
            break;}

            case 2:
            {scale="Celsius";
            break;}

            case 3:
            {scale="Kelvin";
            break;}

            default:
            {scale= "There was an error in your choice!";}
        }

        return scale;

    }



    private static String toScale(int userChoice)
    {

        Scanner userIn= new Scanner(System.in);



        System.out.print("What scale would you like to convert to?"+
                          "1: Fahrenheit" + 
                          "2: Celsius" + 
                          "3: Kelvin" + 
                          "Please enter 1, 2, or 3: ");


        String scale2="";

        switch(userChoice)
        {
            case 1:
            {scale2= "Fahrenheit";
            break;}

            case 2:
            {scale2="Celsius";
            break;}

            case 3:
            {scale2="Kelvin";
            break;}

            default:
            {scale2= "There was an error in your choice!";}
        }

        return scale2;

    }



    public static double convert()
    {
        double farToKel;
        double farToCel;
        double celToKel;
        double celToFar;
        double kelToFar;
        double kelToCel;
        int scale1=0;
        double converts;

        if(scaleOne(scale1)=="Fahrenheit" && toScale(scale1)=="Kelvin")        
        {
         converts=farToKel=(getTemp()+459.67)* 5/9;
        }

        else if(scaleOne(scale1)=="Fahrenheit" && toScale(scale1)=="Celsius")
        {
         converts=farToCel=(getTemp()-32)*5/9;
        }

        else if(scaleOne(scale1)=="Celsius" && toScale(scale1)=="Kelvin")
        {
         converts=celToKel=getTemp()+273.15;
        }

        else if(scaleOne(scale1)=="Celsius" && toScale(scale1)=="Fahrenheit")
        {
         converts=celToFar=getTemp()*9/5+32;
        }

        else if(scaleOne(scale1)=="Kelvin" && toScale(scale1)=="Fahrenheit")
        {
         converts=kelToFar=getTemp()*9/5-459.67;
        }

        else
        { 
         converts=kelToCel=getTemp()-276.15;
        }

        return converts;
    }








    }
```

And here is what it compiles

run:
Enter a temperature to convert 100
What scale is your temp currently in?1: Fahrenheit2: Celsius3: KelvinPlease enter 1, 2, or 3: What scale would you like to convert to?1: Fahrenheit2: Celsius3: KelvinPlease enter 1, 2, or 3: What scale is your temp currently in?1: Fahrenheit2: Celsius3: KelvinPlease enter 1, 2, or 3: What scale is your temp currently in?1: Fahrenheit2: Celsius3: KelvinPlease enter 1, 2, or 3: What scale is your temp currently in?1: Fahrenheit2: Celsius3: KelvinPlease enter 1, 2, or 3: What scale is your temp currently in?1: Fahrenheit2: Celsius3: KelvinPlease enter 1, 2, or 3: What scale is your temp currently in?1: Fahrenheit2: Celsius3: KelvinPlease enter 1, 2, or 3: Enter a temperature to convert 2
What scale would you like to convert to?1: Fahrenheit2: Celsius3: KelvinPlease enter 1, 2, or 3: Your final temp is: -274.15There was an error in your choice!BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 33 seconds)

Its like it is not compiling in the right order, or getting the correct information in the right order and get some information over and over again. Once you enter in the numeric temp, it prompts you for the scale but not just once it prints that out a bunch of times, then you enter your choice for the first scale and it just goes all the way to completion without you entering in your choice for toScale.

Comment: What do you mean by Incorrectly?

Comment: Sorry I am going to edit my original post to include what it compiles.

Comment: Well, first of you decleared a lot of local variables inside the main method without ever using them.

Comment: You are obviously a student. (I hope, or at least a non-programmer). So I am going to say a couple things that hopefully will help. Your design is needlessly complex and revisiting that will help illuminate the issues. Basically you don't need separate methods for grabbing user input. You also only need to grab two pieces of input. That's a hint. Good luck on your homework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the comments inserted and corrections made in your code below.

```
public class TempConverter {

    // variables that are needed in more than one method must be declared outside the methods
    // (static since the methods are static; not recommended, but let it be for now)
    static double temp1;
    static String scale1;
    static String scale2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // get rid of unused variables
        char cont = 'E';

        do {
            // input
            // save all inputs to variables
            temp1 = getTemp();
            // Java parameters are pass by value, so to get a value out of the method, use the returned value
            // then you don’t need the parameter
            scale1 = scaleOne();
            scale2 = toScale();

            // process
            // don’t call toScale() again, or the user will be prompted again,
            // instead, use the value already stored in scale2
            System.out.print("Your final temp is: " + convert() + ' ' + scale2);

            // you should set cont to something if you want the loop to repeat

        } while (cont == 'N');
    }

    private static double getTemp() {
        double temp;
        Scanner userIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a temperature to convert ");
        while (!userIn.hasNextDouble()) {
            System.out.println("That is not a valid temperature!");
            System.out.print("Re-enter a temperature: ");
            userIn.next();
        }
        temp = userIn.nextDouble();

        return temp;
    }

    private static String scaleOne() {

        Scanner userIn = new Scanner(System.in);

        // \n is a line break for readability
        System.out.print("What scale is your temp currently in?" 
                + "\n1: Fahrenheit" 
                + "\n2: Celsius" 
                + "\n3: Kelvin"
                + "\nPlease enter 1, 2, or 3: ");

        // read a value from the user
        int userChoice = userIn.nextInt();

        String scale = "";

        switch (userChoice) {
        case 1: {
            scale = "Fahrenheit";
            break;
        }

        case 2: {
            scale = "Celsius";
            break;
        }

        case 3: {
            scale = "Kelvin";
            break;
        }

        default: {
            scale = "There was an error in your choice!";
        }
        }

        return scale;

    }

    private static String toScale() {

        Scanner userIn = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("What scale would you like to convert to?" + "1: Fahrenheit" + "2: Celsius" + "3: Kelvin"
                + "Please enter 1, 2, or 3: ");

        String scale2 = "";

        int userChoice = userIn.nextInt();

        // ideally should not accept the same scale as scale1 (from scale)
        switch (userChoice) {
        case 1: {
            scale2 = "Fahrenheit";
            break;
        }

        case 2: {
            scale2 = "Celsius";
            break;
        }

        case 3: {
            scale2 = "Kelvin";
            break;
        }

        default: {
            scale2 = "There was an error in your choice!";
        }
        }

        return scale2;

    }

    public static double convert() {
        // need only one variable for result
        double converts;

        // don’t call methods again, use variables
        // don’t use == for comparing strings, use .equals
        // typo: the second scale corrected to scale2
        if (scale1.equals("Fahrenheit") && scale2.equals("Kelvin")) {
            // don’t call getTemp() again
            converts = (temp1 + 459.67) * 5 / 9;
        }

        else if (scale1.equals("Fahrenheit") && scale2.equals("Celsius")) {
            converts = (temp1 - 32) * 5 / 9;
        }

        else if (scale1.equals("Celsius") && scale2.equals("Kelvin")) {
            converts = temp1 + 273.15;
        }

        else if (scale1.equals("Celsius") && scale2.equals("Fahrenheit")) {
            converts = temp1 * 9 / 5 + 32;
        }

        else if (scale1.equals("Kelvin") && scale2.equals("Fahrenheit")) {
            converts = temp1 * 9 / 5 - 459.67;
        }

        else { // Kelvin to Celsius
            converts = temp1 - 276.15;
        }

        return converts;
    }

}
```

I believe it basically works now.

Comment: I like the idea from a couple of the other answers to pass scale1 and scale2 as arguments to `convert()` rather than having static fields, I should have done the same probably with temp1 too.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{


    String scaleOne;
    String scaleTwo;

    System.out.println("What scale is your temp currently in?\n"+
            "1: Fahrenheit\n" +
            "2: Celsius\n" +
            "3: Kelvin\n" +
            "Please enter 1, 2, or 3: \n");

    scaleOne = getScale();

    System.out.println("What scale would you like to convert to?\n"+
            "1: Fahrenheit\n" +
            "2: Celsius\n" +
            "3: Kelvin\n" +
            "Please enter 1, 2, or 3:\n ");

    scaleTwo = getScale();
    System.out.print("Your final temp is: " +convert(scaleOne,scaleTwo));


}
private static double getTemp()
{
    double temp;
    Scanner userIn= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a temperature to convert ");
    while(!userIn.hasNextDouble())
    {
        System.out.println("That is not a valid temperature!");
        System.out.println("Re-enter a temperature: ");
        userIn.next();
    }
    temp=userIn.nextDouble();

    return temp;
}

private static String getScale()
{

    Scanner userIn= new Scanner(System.in);

    String scale="";

    switch(userIn.nextInt())
    {
        case 1:
            scale= "Fahrenheit";
            break;

        case 2:
            scale="Celsius";
            break;

        case 3:
            scale="Kelvin";
            break;

        default:
            scale= "There was an error in your choice!";
    }

    return scale;

}
```

Change the main function accordingly as well as the scaleone() and toScale() functions. Your code has a lot of problems that cannot be addressed individually. Feel free to ask for any clarification on the answer

Answer (score 1):

You have to believe compiler is doing its job correctly. Error lies in your logic. I assume you are trying to create a program to convert temperature from nay of 3 formats to other format.

1. While calling `scaleOne(scale1);` method you have provided an hard coded value `0` as an argument and never changed it inside method. at the same time you are trying to get input from user. For taking user input you need to add `int userChoice = userIn.nextInt();` inside your method body. 
   This will return an sting value which you need to store in `sacle1` variable in your main method.
2. Similarly for `toScale()` method you need to make it non-parameterized and take input from user inside method. 
   This will again return an sting value which you need to store in `sacle2` variable in your main method.
3. Now while calling your convert method you need to pass `scale1` and `scale2` as arguments. I don't understand what is logic behind calling `scaleOne()` and `toScale()` methods again in each if conditions. This is the cause your code is again and again asking for temperature type choice. I have removed them with `scale1` and `scale2` variables in my solution. 
   Always remember, never use `==` operator for `String` comparison. Always use `equals()` or `equalsEgnoreCase()`  method of string class.

I have made changes in your code and tried to get more specific solution as you needed. Hope this will help. Don't forget to vote up.

```
    public class TempConverter {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String scale1;
    String scale2;   
        //input
       scale1 =scaleOne();
       scale2 = toScale();
    //process
    System.out.print("Your final temp is: " +convert(scale1, scale2));
}   
    private static double getTemp()
    {
         double temp;
         Scanner userIn= new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.print("Enter a temperature to convert ");
         while(!userIn.hasNextDouble())
         {
          System.out.println("That is not a valid temperature!");
          System.out.print("Re-enter a temperature: ");
          userIn.next();
         }
         temp=userIn.nextDouble();
         return temp;
    }

    private static String scaleOne()        {

        Scanner userIn= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What scale is your temp currently in?"+
                          "1: Fahrenheit" + 
                          "2: Celsius" + 
                          "3: Kelvin" + 
                          "Please enter 1, 2, or 3: ");
       int userChoice = userIn.nextInt();
        String scale="";
        switch(userChoice)
        {
            case 1:
            {scale= "Fahrenheit";
            break;}
            case 2:
            {scale="Celsius";
            break;}
            case 3:
            {scale="Kelvin";
            break;}
            default:
            {scale= "There was an error in your choice!";}
        }
        return scale;
    }



    private static String toScale(){
        Scanner userIn= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What scale would you like to convert to?"+
                          "1: Fahrenheit" + 
                          "2: Celsius" + 
                          "3: Kelvin" + 
                          "Please enter 1, 2, or 3: ");
        String scale2="";
        int userChoice =  userIn.nextInt();
        switch(userChoice)
        {
            case 1:
            {scale2= "Fahrenheit";
            break;}
            case 2:
            {scale2="Celsius";
            break;}
            case 3:
            {scale2="Kelvin";
            break;}
            default:
            {scale2= "There was an error in your choice!";}
        }
        return scale2;
    }

    public static double convert(String scale1, String scale2)
    {       
        double converts;

        if(scale1.equalsIgnoreCase("Fahrenheit") && scale2.equalsIgnoreCase("Kelvin"))        
        {
         converts=(getTemp()+459.67)* 5/9;
        }

        else if(scale1.equalsIgnoreCase("Fahrenheit") && scale2.equalsIgnoreCase("Celsius"))
        {
         converts=(getTemp()-32)*5/9;
        }

        else if(scale1.equalsIgnoreCase("Celsius") && scale2.equalsIgnoreCase("Kelvin"))
        {
         converts=getTemp()+273.15;
        }

        else if(scale1.equalsIgnoreCase("Celsius") && scale2.equalsIgnoreCase("Fahrenheit"))
        {
         converts=getTemp()*9/5+32;
        }

        else if(scale1.equalsIgnoreCase("Kelvin") && scale1.equalsIgnoreCase("Fahrenheit"))
        {
         converts=getTemp()*9/5-459.67;
        }

        else
        { 
         converts=getTemp()-276.15;
        }

        return converts;
    }}
```

Answer (score 1):

after all is said and done I completed it and it runs correctly and as requested in class. Thanks for all the feed back!

```
    package tempconverter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TempConverter 
{
        static double temp1;
        static String scale1;
        static String scale2;
        static double conv;


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        char cont='N';

        do
        {   menueOne();



            menueCatch();

            cont=contOption();




        }while(cont=='Y');
    }   
        private static void menueOne()
        {
            System.out.print("Please make a selection."
                               +"\n1: Begin"
                               +"\n2: Exit"
                               +"\n");
        }

        private static void menueCatch()
        {   
            Scanner userIn= new Scanner(System.in);
            int userChoice=userIn.nextInt();

            String input="";
            switch(userChoice)
            {

                case 1:
                {
                 temp1=getTemp();
                 scale1=scaleOne();
                 scale2=toScale();
                 conv=convert();
                 displayConversion();
                 break;
                }

                case 2:
                {

                 break;
                }
            }
        }

        private static double getTemp()
        {
             double temp;
             double currentTemp;
             Scanner userIn= new Scanner(System.in);
             System.out.print("Enter a temperature to convert as a digit(ex: 100, 32, 10, 0):  ");
             while(!userIn.hasNextDouble())
             {
              System.out.println("That is not a valid temperature!");
              System.out.print("Re-enter a temperature: ");
              userIn.next();
             }
             temp=userIn.nextDouble();



             return temp;
        }

        private static String scaleOne()
        {

            Scanner userIn= new Scanner(System.in);



            System.out.print("What scale is your temp currently in?"+
                              "\n1: Fahrenheit" + 
                              "\n2: Celsius" + 
                              "\n3: Kelvin" + 
                              "\nPlease enter 1, 2, or 3: ");

            int userChoice = userIn.nextInt();

            String scale="";

            switch(userChoice)
            {
                case 1:
                {scale= "Fahrenheit";
                break;}

                case 2:
                {scale="Celsius";
                break;}

                case 3:
                {scale="Kelvin";
                break;}

                default:
                {scale= "There was an error in your choice!";}
            }

            return scale;

        }



        private static String toScale()
        {

            Scanner userIn= new Scanner(System.in);



            System.out.print("What scale would you like to convert to?"+
                              "\n1: Fahrenheit" + 
                              "\n2: Celsius" + 
                              "\n3: Kelvin" + 
                              "\nPlease enter 1, 2, or 3: ");

            int userChoice = userIn.nextInt();

            String scale2="";

            switch(userChoice)
            {
                case 1:
                {scale2= "Fahrenheit";
                break;}

                case 2:
                {scale2="Celsius";
                break;}

                case 3:
                {scale2="Kelvin";
                break;}

                default:
                {scale2= "There was an error in your choice!";}
            }

            return scale2;

        }



        public static double convert()
        {

            double converts;

            if (scale1.equals("Fahrenheit") && scale2.equals("Kelvin")) {

            converts = (temp1 + 459.67) * (5.0 / 9.0);
        }

        else if (scale1.equals("Fahrenheit") && scale2.equals("Celsius")) {
            converts = (temp1 - 32) * (5.0 / 9.0);
        }

        else if (scale1.equals("Celsius") && scale2.equals("Kelvin")) {
            converts = temp1 + 273.15;
        }

        else if (scale1.equals("Celsius") && scale2.equals("Fahrenheit")) {
            converts = temp1 * (9.0 / 5.0) + 32;
        }

        else if (scale1.equals("Kelvin") && scale2.equals("Fahrenheit")) {
            converts = temp1 * (9.0 / 5.0) - 459.67;
        }

        else { // Kelvin to Celsius
            converts = temp1 - 276.15;
        }

        return converts;
        }

        private static void displayConversion()
        {
            System.out.print("Your final temp is: " +conv+' '+scale2+' ');
        }

         private static char contOption()
        {
            char answer;
        Scanner userIn=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("\nDo you wish to convert another temp?(Y/N): ");
        answer=userIn.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);

        return answer;
        }    






        }
```